# Microsoft.Azure.Graphs : how to cast the result to a type?

Tags: .net, azure, facebook-graph-api, gremlin

When following this tutorial at [tutorial-develop-graph-dotnet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/tutorial-develop-graph-dotnet) all Gremlin Query examples are returning a dynamic result.

Like:

```
IDocumentQuery<dynamic> query = client.CreateGremlinQuery<dynamic>(graph, "g.V().hasLabel('person')");
dynamic result in await query.ExecuteNextAsync();
```

The result is something like:

```
{"id":"thomas","label":"person","type":"vertex","properties":{"firstName":[{"id":"8fec3d0f-7290-4e80-9f38-9306de998579","value":"Thomas"}],"age":[{"id":"932879da-55c0-4dbc-b68c-fb3ef1e1827a","value":44}]}}
```

But how to use the `CreateGremlinQuery` and `ExecuteNextAsync` in order to return a normal class `Person` ?

```
public class Person
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is like:

1]
Annotate the person class:

```
public class Person
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("firstName")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("lastName")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("age")]
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

2]
Cast the result to a JObject and loop the properties:

```
IDocumentQuery<dynamic> query = client.CreateGremlinQuery<dynamic>(graph, "g.V().hasLabel('person')");
while (query.HasMoreResults)
{
    foreach (JObject item in await query.ExecuteNextAsync<dynamic>())
    {
        var properties = (JObject)item["properties"];

        var personAsJObject = new JObject();
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            if (property.Value is JArray valueArray)
            {
                personAsJObject.Add(property.Key, valueArray.First["value"]);
            }
        }

        var person = personAsJObject.ToObject<Person>(); // Real person here
    }
}
```